# Hidden HTML Element not Disappear

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

On my website I hide a container by setting `display` css property to `none`. But in the lastest version of Google Chrome it doesn't work anymore (but it worked on earlier versions).

You can reproduce it by visiting [this page](http://xandaro.com/en/s/p/demo) and clicking on `Contact` and then on `Team`. Contact tab still displayed with `display: none`

[image]

Comment: `Contact` tab for me is no longer displayed in Chrome after clicking `Team`.

Comment: @Madbreaks, it actually does still display for me. The map remains in the background, cut off by the photo.

Comment: Yep, stays displayed for me too. Strange!

Comment: @Madbreaks do you use the lastest version of chrome (v24)?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 24.0.1312.52

Comment: I'm rocking 24.0.1312.52

Comment: Also 24.0.1312.52, Windows 8 64bit, yet I see the issue exactly as described.

Comment: Maybe it's a Windows vs Mac issue. Anyone want to post a video screencap of the problem?

Comment: @showdev, done. I'm also using 24.0.1312.52 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Works fine for me 26.0.1384.2 dev, on Mac OS.

Comment: Works for me on v24 for Mac but not v24 for Windows

Comment: It's a bug in Google Chrome as Brandon described. I fixed it by adding `min-height` to the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a bug in Chrome.

Your issue seems very similar to [this one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=169779), which was opened 3 days ago. `display:none;` isn't working, and is being overlapped by `display:block;`.

There hasn't been a response from the Chromium team so far, but you can track that ticket in case a workaround is posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no CSS guru, but I think the problem stems from the fact you are floating the `div` tags within `.employees` and not clearing them.

If I add `<div class="clear"></div>` after the `div` tags within `div class="employees"` and `div class="contact-information"` and also add a `height` attribute to `employees` then it seems to be resolved.

It's fine in Firefox (Windows 7 64bit, but not Chrome for me). The above fixes it in Chrome for me.